# What Fonts Come Pre-Installed on Windows and don't Require a License?

Tags: fonts

I'm trying to get into development, and I'm wondering about fonts. What fonts, if any, come pre-installed on Windows 10 and are free to commercially use? Any help would be appreciated! :D

Answer (score 0):

There is a list of pre installed fonts in windows.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_typefaces_included_with_Microsoft_Windows